# Is there an OnDrawComplete type event in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, events, delegates, draw

I'm looking for an event that fires off once all form elements in a silverlight window has been drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the UserControl.SizeChanged event for that, just use it the first time the event is called and your controls should be rendered at that time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to use it for. In WPF, the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event always fires *after* the template has been applied, however in Silverlight, that is not *guaranteed* to be true. As an alternative, you may want to work with the `FrameworkElement.LayoutUpdated` event. This may, however, become very expensive if you have lots of moving parts in your visual tree.